# programmatically setting custom xml layout elements

Tags: java, android, custom-view

In my code I have a class title 'CustomView' that has two TextView fields and extends Relative layout. One instantiation CustomView inflates it's self with an xml layout out called 'custom_view_layout' which displays two text fields, also on instantiation these two text views are equated to CustomView's text views.

In my 'main' xml layout file I have a custom tag for 'CustomView' as you can see from the xml this tag has some layout parameters. What I want to is programatically instantiate CustomView, populate it's text view and then 'set' the custom view in my main xml layout file to this instantiated view. Id like to do this in a manner that is slicker than passing the cusomview tags layout parameters to my instance of CustomView and then replacing my custom view tag with the instance of Custom View.

In my code I have commented out two failed attempts at doing this. Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

The Custom View Class:

```
package com.customviewsetexample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomView extends RelativeLayout {

    TextView textView1;
    TextView textView2;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initView(context);
        this.textView1 = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        this.textView2 = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView(context);
        this.textView1 = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        this.textView2 = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    }

    private void initView(Context context){
        this.inflate(context, R.layout.custom_view_layout, this);
    }

    public void populateCustomView(String string_1, String string_2){
        System.out.println("Started");
        this.textView1.setText(string_1);
        System.out.println("mid");
        this.textView2.setText(string_2);
        System.out.println("end");
    }

}
```

My activity class with my two attempts commented out:

```
package com.customviewsetexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomViewSetExampleActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    String string_1;
    String string_2;
    CustomView customView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String string_1 = "String 1";
        String string_2 = "String 2";
        customView = new CustomView(this);
        customView.populateCustomView(string_1, string_2);
        CustomView mainCustomView = (CustomView)findViewById(R.id.mainCustomView);

        /*
         //This Does nothing
        mainCustomView = customView;
         */

        /*
       //Throws Error see below
       mainCustomView.updateViewLayout(customView, mainCustomView.getLayoutParams());
        */
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.customviewsetexample.CustomView     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"       
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainCustomView"
    >
```

custom_view_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:layout_height="wrap_content"    android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></TextView>
    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:layout_height="wrap_content"     android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"></TextView>
```

Error message from Update View attempt:

```
09-21 01:02:40.121: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1592): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
09-21 01:02:40.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1592): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.customviewsetexample/com.customviewsetexample.CustomViewSetExampleActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid LayoutParams supplied to com.customviewsetexample.CustomView@43762b20
09-21 01:02:40.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2401)
09-21 01:02:40.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
09-21 01:02:40.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
09-21 01:02:40.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
09-21 01:02:40.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-21 01:02:40.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-21 01:02:40.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
09-21 01:02:40.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-21 01:02:40.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-21 01:02:40.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
09-21 01:02:40.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
09-21 01:02:40.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-21 01:02:40.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1592): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid LayoutParams supplied to com.customviewsetexample.CustomView@43762b20
09-21 01:02:40.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.view.ViewGroup.updateViewLayout(ViewGroup.java:1759)
09-21 01:02:40.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at com.customviewsetexample.CustomViewSetExampleActivity.onCreate(CustomViewSetExampleActivity.java:34)
09-21 01:02:40.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
09-21 01:02:40.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
09-21 01:02:40.130: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1592):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

In you `CustomView` class at the point where you are trying to inflate the view, firstly you need to register for Layout inflate service.

Pass the correct context to the constructor of your class, then use the context you've passed to register for inflating, and then inflate.

Try something like:

```
      private void initView(Context context){
        LayoutInflater infl = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 View temp = infl.inflate(R.layout.test, null); //contains your entire xml ofcourse
        }
```

When you are trying to set your custom view to the main xml, you can do it quickly, like inflating your main xml, and then use `.addView(customview)` you can do this right before you do `setContentView()` if it is not against your requirements or flow.

There are a lot of things to be reworked here.

Comment: Hi Nikola, thank you for your response. I have run a few test and CustomView is being inflated properly in insantiation with my current code. What I'm hoping to find is an elegant way of equating that instantiated view to a view of the same type in main.xml such that it preserves the layout parameters set for that view in the xml.

Comment: Ofcourse you can add it with specific layoutparams. `.addView(view, layoutparams)`